# Is there a stored procedure to work out what indexes I should add?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, indices

Firstly, apologies if this is on the wrong site.

Secondly, I vaguely remember from a couple of years ago, when trying to heavily index a SQL Server 2005 db that there was a stored procedure that I could run that would output stats on tables that would help judge where indexes should be placed.

Am I right in this, or was I dreaming it?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and above have a [missing indexes DMV](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/Identify_Missing_Indexes_Using_SQL_Server_DMVs_p1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Youll be wanting to look at the Performance Dashboard.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2007/03/29/sql-server-2005-performance-dashboard-reports.aspx